# how to hide specific items in a listview that is dynamically loaded

Tags: android, listview

I need some help regarding how to hide some of the list Items when **clicked on a button** and the listView is dynamically loaded from the DB. I know we can use `tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` but that is only in the case of when we have the id of that view from xml but mine case is different? So any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can set tag to each row and work with that instead id that you don't nd change visibility of that row to Gone or Invisible

Comment: @user3294034  use a SimpleCursorAdapter and on button click call swapCursor with a Cursor that holds data according to your search criteria

Answer (score 0):

Remove the items from the list, which you are passing to the adapter. pass the new list and call notifyDataSetChanged() for that adapter.

Comment: this is deleting , not hiding.

Comment: listview calculates the number of views based upon the count it gets in the getcount() method. Unless that is changed, the listview will always populate that many views for the list. you can try to place the items, you want to hide, at the end of the list and pass the number of remaining items as the count. It may work but may not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Save the data for populating the listView in an ArrayList, then populate the listView from that arraylist. When clicking the button, delete the items in the arraylist and call `listView.notifydatasetchanged();`

Comment: this is deleting , not hiding.

Comment: Could be

((TextView)getItem(position)).setVisibility(View.Invisible);

for each position you want to hide

Answer (score 0):

If for example using an ArrayAdapter for your ListView you will have a List (like an ArrayList).
If you keep a reference to that List you can do something like:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
{
  myList.remove(position);
  myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        
}
```

Comment: this is deleting , not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

```
        View v = null;
        if (arg1 == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.adapter_item, null);
        } else {
            v = arg1;
        }

        txt = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.txt);
        btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                txt.setVisibity(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        return v;
```